# Slow down on tap?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Basically I've got a game going, that I've been working on using `libGDX`. I have a `character`, that moves forward automatically. And what the user taps on the screen/clicks, I want the `character`s speed to decrease. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help would be great.

My `ScrollHandler`:

```
package com.kilobolt.GameObjects;

import com.kilobolt.GameWorld.GameWorld;
import com.kilobolt.ZBHelpers.AssetLoader;

public class ScrollHandler {

    private Grass frontGrass, backGrass;
    private Pipe pipe1, pipe2, pipe3;
    public static final int SCROLL_SPEED = -1000;
    public static final int PIPE_GAP = 49;

    private GameWorld gameWorld;

    public ScrollHandler(GameWorld gameWorld, float yPos) {
        this.gameWorld = gameWorld;
        frontGrass = new Grass(0, yPos, 143, 11, SCROLL_SPEED);
        backGrass = new Grass(frontGrass.getTailX(), yPos, 143, 11,
                SCROLL_SPEED);

        pipe1 = new Pipe(210, 0, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED, yPos);
        pipe2 = new Pipe(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP, 0, 22, 70, SCROLL_SPEED,
                yPos);
        pipe3 = new Pipe(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP, 0, 22, 60, SCROLL_SPEED,
                yPos);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // Update our objects
        frontGrass.update(delta);
        backGrass.update(delta);
        pipe1.update(delta);
        pipe2.update(delta);
        pipe3.update(delta);

        // Check if any of the pipes are scrolled left,
        // and reset accordingly
        if (pipe1.isScrolledLeft()) {
            pipe1.reset(pipe3.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);
        } else if (pipe2.isScrolledLeft()) {
            pipe2.reset(pipe1.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);

        } else if (pipe3.isScrolledLeft()) {
            pipe3.reset(pipe2.getTailX() + PIPE_GAP);
        }

        // Same with grass
        if (frontGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            frontGrass.reset(backGrass.getTailX());

        } else if (backGrass.isScrolledLeft()) {
            backGrass.reset(frontGrass.getTailX());

        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        frontGrass.stop();
        backGrass.stop();
        pipe1.stop();
        pipe2.stop();
        pipe3.stop();
    }

    public boolean collides(Bird bird) {

        if (!pipe1.isScored()
                && pipe1.getX() + (pipe1.getWidth() / 2) < bird.getX()
                        + bird.getWidth()) {
            addScore(1);
            pipe1.setScored(true);
            AssetLoader.coin.play();
        } else if (!pipe2.isScored()
                && pipe2.getX() + (pipe2.getWidth() / 2) < bird.getX()
                        + bird.getWidth()) {
            addScore(1);
            pipe2.setScored(true);
            AssetLoader.coin.play();

        } else if (!pipe3.isScored()
                && pipe3.getX() + (pipe3.getWidth() / 2) < bird.getX()
                        + bird.getWidth()) {
            addScore(1);
            pipe3.setScored(true);
            AssetLoader.coin.play();

        }

        return (pipe1.collides(bird) || pipe2.collides(bird) || pipe3
                .collides(bird));
    }

    private void addScore(int increment) {
        gameWorld.addScore(increment);
    }

    public Grass getFrontGrass() {
        return frontGrass;
    }

    public Grass getBackGrass() {
        return backGrass;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe1() {
        return pipe1;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe2() {
        return pipe2;
    }

    public Pipe getPipe3() {
        return pipe3;
    }

}
```

My `Bird` :

```
package com.kilobolt.GameObjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.kilobolt.ZBHelpers.AssetLoader;

public class Bird {

    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 velocity;
    private Vector2 acceleration;

    private float rotation;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private boolean isAlive;

    private Circle boundingCircle;

    public Bird(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        acceleration = new Vector2(0, 460);
        boundingCircle = new Circle();
        isAlive = true;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {

        velocity.add(acceleration.cpy().scl(delta));

        if (velocity.y > 200) {
            velocity.y = 200;
        }

        position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));

        // Set the circle's center to be (9, 6) with respect to the bird.
        // Set the circle's radius to be 6.5f;
        boundingCircle.set(position.x + 9, position.y + 6, 6.5f);


        }



    public boolean isFalling() {
        return velocity.y > 110;
    }

    public boolean shouldntFlap() {
        return velocity.y > 70 || !isAlive;
    }

    public void onClick() {
        if (isAlive) {
            AssetLoader.flap.play();
            velocity.y = -140;
        }
    }

    public void die() {
        isAlive = false;
        velocity.y = 0;
    }

    public void decelerate() {
        acceleration.y = 0;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return position.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return position.y;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public float getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public Circle getBoundingCircle() {
        return boundingCircle;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return isAlive;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aw, I thought we could've helped out. Too bad I don't have a copy of your code on my computer. Sorry.

Comment: Could you include some of your current code?

Comment: Just the corresponding part? @JustinJasmann

Comment: I have given a suggestion but i need to see your movement/speed code in order to present you with a full solution

Comment: Thanks. Why is it that you want the character's speed to decrease if you are making a flappy bird style game? just wondering

Comment: Since my game has enemies that float up and down, I want the speed to decrease so that then the bird can avoid them, since they have a fixed speed. Also thanks for helping me out. @ylun

Comment: no problem, glad i could be of assistance. Let me know if you have any further issues with your game.

Comment: @ylun Are you willing to partner? If you're willing to discuss let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my recommendation:

Whenever the `MouseListener` detects a click, have it run something along the lines of `playerSpeed -=` or `playerSpeed = playerSpeed - *some other number*`. That way, whenever the click occurs, the player slows down.

Now, if you wanted to have it so that when a click occurs, the player slows down and when another click occurs, the player speeds up again, use a `boolean` that toggles a slow speed and a fast speed when a click occurs.

Comment: right, so which method specifically are you having issues with, `onClick()` or `decelerate`>

Comment: I'm just fairly new and didn't know what to use. But since I'm doing Android and iOS would `MouseListener` still work?

Comment: you're right, no it would not. I can see that when you are calling the `decelerate` method, you are setting the deceleration to be 0 which is wrong. It should be in the opposite direction of the velocity (do a check for which direction the velocity is and adjust accordingly)